# Controlling page breaks when printing to duplex printer

Tags: activereports

I'm using the new fixed page layout report in active reports 7, with a fixed cover page and a variable number of overflow pages. When it's printed the user can select a number of these reports to print at once, and the data for the report is adjusted accordingly. The report has grouping defined to start a new cover page for each group. How can I ensure that when printing to a double sided printer that each cover page is printed to a new sheet of paper? For example, consider the simple case where there is only a cover sheet and no overflow. If the dataset contains data for three such pages, how can I ensure that a new sheet is printed for each one, rather than the second being printed on the back of the first?

An alternative solution would be to split the data before it gets to the report, then repeatedly create and print the report for each group. To do this I would need to ask the user to select a printer for the first copy, but then use the same printer for subsequent invocations. How can I determine which printer the user selected, then pass that printer to the second, third, etc invocations? I could create my own printer selection dialog, I guess, but it would be useful to know if I can retrieve the information from the built in one

Comment: does this work for you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619698/programmatically-insert-page-break-in-activereports

Comment: I don't think so. I'm not using section reports for this report, so all the stuff I'm used to about events within the report generation no longer appears to be applicable. To be honest I'm not liking the fixed page reports as they seem to offer far less control than I'm used to from active reports. The concept is ideal for this report, but the implementation is lacking. Also, there doesn't appear to be any property of the grouping to specify a new page should be used

Comment: makes sense, missed the crucial bit of "fixed page" template.. I believe by the time the layout is being processed, eidting page settings is too late, as these changes wont come into effect anymore (and that is by design). I will keep looking if there is a solution. - or may be ask the component guys' in the meantime

Comment: Posted the question early last week, no response to date. Not the most active of forums. I've a bit of time scheduled to come back to this at the end of the current sprint next week, I think I'll be focusing on the alternative solution I mentioned

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any way to do this with AR currently. It's a great idea though and I'll make sure the ActiveReports team considers this in the future. I'll also ask around and see if anyone else has ideas within GrapeCity/ComponentOne.